# How to write a correct SQL query?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with following columns:
city name, population, year (year is when the data about population was collected)

In the table there can be the same city for more than 1 year, for example:

```
New York 7999999 2019
New York 8000000 2020
New York 7999998 2018 
London 7000000 2020
London 7000000 2016
Moscow 12000000 2017
```

(So there're 3 records about New York, 2 about London and 1 about Moscow)

I need a query to get the newest records about every city.
So here the result will be:

```
New York 8000000 2020
London 7000000 2020
Moscow 12000000 2017
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
SELECT town, amount, date FROM townlist
WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM townlist)
```

In general you need a solution to  group the list by town - with the newest entry on top: another approach

```
SELECT town, amount, date 
FROM (SELECT * FROM townlist ORDER BY date DESC) as sortedTable
GROUP BY town
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the latest record per city. A cross-database solution that usually performs well is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.year = (select max(t1.year) from mytable t1 where t1.town = t.town)
```

A multi-column index on `(town, year)` would speed up this query.